# Getting error while running Pyinstaller packaged Python script

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

I am updating my current software that was written in python. It has been packed with pyinstaller --onefile myfile.pyw thousand times before without any issue but suddenly this time after the packing process done and I turn on the .exe file, this is the error I get.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91ig2.png)

I tried to pack with the very simple code but nothing happen when open the .exe file.

Thinking that something has happed to pyinstaller, I attemped to uninstall and reinstall it several times but still not work.

Please somebody help me.

Comment: I do not think the error message is: Please somebody help me. Can you add the full `pyinstaller` command and the exact error message you get.

Comment: sorry for making you confuse, I have reattached the image. Please somebody help me is just my words. BTW, I used 'Pyinstaller --onefile mycode.pyw'

Answer (score -1):

Maybe there is a problem of environment Variable. Hope so it's work